# Error-Page not found (404) on pressing Submit Button on Login Page

Tags: django, authentication, django-login

Got Error-Page not found (404) on pressing Submit Button on Login Page

```
Request Method:GET

URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/login.html?username=dfg&password=dfg

Using the URLconf defined in app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='login']

about [name='about']

afterlogin [name='afterlogin']

admin/

The current path, login.html, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I want to ask 2 things

- why is it taking about `Request Method:GET` when my `views.py` says

```py
    def afterlogin(request):
        return render(request,'pages/afterlogin.html')
    def login(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            messages.error(request,'testing error')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            return render(request,'pages/login.html')
```

and my `url.py` in apps

```
    urlpatterns = [
            path('', views.login, name="login"),
            path('about',views.about,name="about"),
            path('afterlogin', views.afterlogin, name="afterlogin"),
            path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

Any solution to solve this problem,Please?

Comment: Did you add login url to settings.py?

Comment: Mr.Karthik I tried but yet the same result Page not found (404).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib import messages,auth
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


 
def about(request):
    return render(request,'pages/admin.html')
def afterlogin(request):
    return render(request,'pages/afterlogin.html')
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect('/afterlogin')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid credentials')
            return redirect('login')
            # User is authenticate  
    else:
        return render(request,'pages/login.html')
  

def r(request):
    return redirect('afterlogin')```
````